# I am done installing a new project using composer create-project silverstripe/installer example, done with .env set-up but i have this on my webpage

Tags: php, frameworks, silverstripe

Deprecated:

```
Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example2/vendor/silverstripe/framework/src/Control/HTTPRequest.php on line 583
Website Error
```

There has been an error
The website server has not been able to respond to your request

i tried `'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example2/vendor/silverstripe/framework/src/Control/HTTPRequest.php'` so that i can locate and change the `${var}` and replace it with `{$var}` but there seems to be nothing of this `'${var}'` sort on line 583

Comment: To avoid the deprecation notice, replace the variable to have the curly braces cover the dollar sign. This pattern is compatible across PHP versions, and does not cause the deprecation notice. use ```echo "Hello {$name}";``` instead of ```${name}```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Also, how is this problem related to MAMP or Composer?

Comment: That code is in the Silverstripe framework core code - editing it directly is not advised. Instead, see my answer for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

> Deprecated: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead

This deprecation warning comes from using PHP 8.2

Silverstripe CMS 4 and its related supported modules are not officially compatible with PHP 8.2 - if you aren't going to explicitly use any new features that come with that PHP version I recommend downgrading to PHP 8.1 for now, or else you can start developing with the Silverstripe CMS 5 beta which *is* explicitly compatible with PHP 8.2

Note that the deprecation warning is just that - a warning. In this case it's just an indication that in some future PHP update the functionality will stop working, but it should be fine now. So you *could* keep using Silverstripe CMS 4 with PHP 8.2 in test or live mode and the error shouldn't display. Just be aware that you may also be hiding other errors if you develop exclusively in those modes.